# T-SQL JSON: How do i search for a value in a JSON array

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

We are using Azure SQL - and have a table called companies where one of the columns contains JSON. The structure for the JSON field is:

```
{
  "DepartmentLink": "https://company.com",
  "ContactName": "John Doe",
  "ContactTitle": "CEO",
  "ContactEmail": "john.doe@company.com",
  "ContactPhone": "xx xx xx xx xx",
  "ContactImage": "https://company.com/xyz.jpg",
  "ZipCodes": [
    "7000",
    "7007",
    "7017",
    "7018",
    "7029"
  ]
}
```

The structure for the Table looks like

```
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[JsonString] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
-- other fields --
```

where [JsonString] has this structure:

```
{
  "DepartmentLink": "https://company.com",
  "ContactName": "John Doe",
  "ContactTitle": "CEO",
  "ContactEmail": "john.doe@company.com",
  "ContactPhone": "xx xx xx xx xx",
  "ContactImage": "https://company.com/xyz.jpg",
  "ZipCodes": [
    "7000",
    "7007",
    "7017",
    "7018",
    "7029"
  ]
}
```

Given a ZipCode .e.g. 7018 I need to find the company which has this ZipCode in the Json Array ZipCodes - and return elements from the record (these elements are all present as ordinary "fields" - so I do not need to return the JSON.).

I'm having problems finding out how to do this. Any suggestions? I'm quite new to JSON in SQL.

Comment: What have you tried? According to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server you should be able to use JSON path to extract the ZIP codes, then filter on them afterwards

Comment: More information from your side would definitely help us, like how you want to perform the search for ZipCode and Company - anyways for a start this query `SELECT value FROM OPENJSON(@jsonObject,'$.ZipCodes')` would give you all the ZipCode (in rows) from the `json` string.

Comment: Edited the question - Tried to explained the problem better

Answer (score 6):

use `OPENJSON` and `CROSS APPLY` to shred the zip codes array then add a `WHERE` clause with your filter, something like this:

```
SELECT *, JSON_VALUE( yourJSON, '$.DepartmentLink' ) AS DepartmentLink
FROM dbo.Companies 
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON( yourJSON, '$.ZipCodes') x
WHERE x.value = '7000';
```

Answer (score 3):

It tried this and it seems to work. Is this a recommendable way to do it?

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Companies]
WHERE EXISTS (
      Select *
      FROM OPENJSON(JsonString,'$.ZipCodes') 
      WHERE Value = '7018'
)
```